Is there a way to change the priority of vscode.FileDecorationProvider?
I have my own vscode.FileDecorationProvider for displaying a 'Dot' icon with accent color for the startup project.
But Git overlapped my color and hint with its own values. Is there a way to change the priority of my vscode.FileDecorationProvider to display it instead of Git?
I want to show my FileDecorationProvider provider
Expected

Instead of Git
Actual

